# Show that $\psi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ defined by $\psi([m])=e^{2\pi\frac{m}{n}i}$ is a representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Show that $\psi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ defined by $\psi([m])=e^{2\pi\frac{m}{n}i}$ is a representation of the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ .

It is easy show that $\psi$ is a homomorphism; in effect:
If $[m_1]$,$[m_2]\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then
$\psi([m_1+m_2])=e^{2\pi\frac{m_1+m_2}{n}i}=e^{2\pi\frac{m_1}{n}i}e^{2\pi\frac{m_2}{n}i}=\psi([m_1])\psi([m_2]).$

My question is: how can I show that $\psi$ is well defined? Can you help me? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in[m]$. Then $x-y=kn$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. So $$\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{(x-y)}{n}\right)=\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{kn}{n}\right)=\exp\left(2\pi ik\right)=1.$$ Hence $\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{x}{n}\right)=\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{y}{n}\right)$.